# Android Studio Layout Editor kept on Auto Zoom Out

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

It's so annoying, I couldn't find any windows or button to disable the auto zoom out every time I scrolled down and click in any area on the xml. It would zoom out 48%-50% and then I need to adjust it manually just to zoom in again. P.S I'm using java for my client wanted.

[image]

Thanks, I really appreciated it!

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: @DougStevenson They're not showing the text. They're showing the IDE tool that has the issue. It happens with any layout XML.